# Split a column in T-SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to using T-SQL,
how do you separate an NVARCHAR column with the following information

```
[3293,"Maria","CA","Auto"]
[67093,"Joana","WA","Manual"]
```

I would like to get 4 columns like this

```
col1   col2    col3  col4
3293   Maria   CA    Auto
67093  Joana   WA    Manual
```

Thanks

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the need for an aggregation.

**Example**

```
Select Col1 = JSON_VALUE([SomeCol],'$[0]')
      ,Col2 = JSON_VALUE([SomeCol],'$[1]')
      ,Col3 = JSON_VALUE([SomeCol],'$[2]')
      ,Col4 = JSON_VALUE([SomeCol],'$[3]')
 From YourTable A
```

**Results**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
3293    Maria   CA      Auto
67093   Joana   WA      Manual
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `openjson` and aggregate:

```
select
 max(case when [key] = 0 then value end) col1,
 max(case when [key] = 1 then value end) col2,
 max(case when [key] = 2 then value end) col3,
 max(case when [key] = 3 then value end) col4
from OpenJson('[3293,"Maria","CA","Auto"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

One more suggestion uses a trick to stuff a json array into another array. This allows for a type-safe(!) and pivot/aggregate-free `WITH`-clause:

Declare a dummy table to provide a showcase (please do this yourself in your next question).

```
DECLARE @dummyTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourJson NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @dummyTable(YourJson) VALUES
 ('[3293,"Maria","CA","Auto"]')
,('[67093,"Joana","WA","Manual"]');
```

--the query

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,JsonValues.*
FROM @dummyTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[',t.YourJson,']'))
            WITH
            (
             TheNumber int           '$[0]'
            ,Firstname nvarchar(100) '$[1]'
            ,[State]   nvarchar(100) '$[2]'
            ,[Type]    nvarchar(100) '$[3]'
            ) JsonValues;
```

The idea in short:

- Using `CONCAT()` we add a `[` and a `]` around your array.
- Now we can use `WITH` specifying the resulting column with name, type and the json path to grab it.

The result:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+--------+
| ID | TheNumber | Firstname | State | Type   |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+--------+
| 1  | 3293      | Maria     | CA    | Auto   |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+--------+
| 2  | 67093     | Joana     | WA    | Manual |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'OpenJson' and pass the column values in a loop.

```
--Step1: Create a Temporary table and add Row_Number

select ROW_NUMBER() over( order by COL) as r,* 
INTO #Temp_table
from YourTable;

--Step2: Declare and set Variables

DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @row INT;
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(250);
set @count= (select COUNT(1) FROM #Temp_table);
SET @row = 1;

--Step3: Create Final table (Here, using temp final table)
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_FINAL 
(COL1 INT,COL2 VARCHAR(100),COL3 VARCHAR(100),COL4 VARCHAR(100));

--Step4: Iterate over loop

WHILE (@row <= @count) BEGIN
    
    SELECT @JSON=COL FROM #Temp_table WHERE @row=r;
    
    INSERT INTO #TEMP_FINAL
    select
    max(case when [key] = 0 then value end) col1,
    max(case when [key] = 1 then value end) col2,
    max(case when [key] = 2 then value end) col3,
    max(case when [key] = 3 then value end) col4
    from OpenJson(@JSON);
    
    SET @row += 1;
END 

--Step5: Select the values

SELECT * FROM #TEMP_FINAL
```

To have understanding, you can review following links

Row_Number: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/
While Loop: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-while-loop-with-simple-examples/

Comment: Please avoid loops... Set-based approaches will always be better than procedural ones...